# In wso2 ei how create multipart request using application/octet-stream response

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

In wso2 ei 6.6 I am calling first api and getting the response application/octet-stream using this response how to create multipart request.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <root>
            <file
                xmlns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd/form-data">$1
            </file>
        </root>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/">
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

If I set like the above payload factory I am getting empty response or encoded binary response. How can I fetch the media type and set multipart in wso2 ei.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by fetching the media type and setting multipart?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear to me whether the problem is with the response of the request but since you mention "How to set multipart"

With the below payload factory you should be able to create a multi part payload including a filename based on the incoming file content.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
<format>
    <root
        xmlns="">
        <file xmlns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd/form-data" filename="$2">$1</file>
    </root>
</format>
<args>
    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/mediate/fileContent"/>
    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/mediate/fileContent/@filename"/>
</args>
```

Source: I hope this blog might help you:

https://www.yenlo.com/blogs/multipart-form-data-uploads-wso2-ei-esb/